# How do I calculate the size in PX of a meta title/description programically?

Tags: google-search, meta-tags, meta-description

I have some meta titles / descriptions which holds some dynamic content. Server side, before rendering the page, I wanna detect if that title / description is too long and fallback to a shorter one if so.

My problem is, that the title length is of cause hugely dependent on what characters are in the string, so I cannot rely on character count, I need to calculate the px length instead.

How would I do that i code - any code?

If I could just find some authoritative source of character sizes in px for google SERP texts I could do the rest easily - but I can't find anything.

PS. I know there are plenty of web tools for doing this, but I need to do in code myself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/118251/1992004

Comment: So there would be no way doing this without actually rendering the text?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31305410/1992004

Comment: The length of the description that Google is willing to show isn't fixed.  Google has experiments running and show different lengths to different experiment groups.   Google shows different lengths on different size screens and for different devices.   It is pointless to try to try to optimize your meta description too much.  Its going to get truncated in some cases and it could show some extra data in other cases.    It isn't even a big deal when Google doesn't show the whole thing because they generally do a decent job of extracting a snippet or truncating it for you.

Comment: Just stick to the general advice of 120 to 150 characters while putting the important text first.  It isn't worth trying to hyper-optimize it to have pixel perfect fit for some user on some device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way,

I calculated the size of each letter in the unicode alphabet, when located between two letters. That gave me a pretty good approximate for the px width of each letter. The width I calculated suing the same settings and fonts as google use and with jQuery string size measurement. Then I got a catalogue of letter widths I could use for approximating string sizes.

This has proven pretty accurate after testing it against some of the SERP test tools out there.